# Expecting your guidance to solve my "EGORefreshTableHeaderView" issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4

I would like to get your attention towards my problem so please bear with me anyway.

I have been using the [EGORefreshTableHeaderView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) it was working super indeed.
It has a function named "refreshLastUpdatedDate". This function is called from two view controllers in my application. So the last updated date time is not maintained properly.

Let me explain " I refresh one view then , when i go and see the other view's last update date it shows the first view's updated date amnd time".I am not able to use the EGORefreshTableHeaderView class between multiple views.

Comment: are you using different instances of EGORefereshTableHeaderView?

Comment: @Ravin: Yes i am using different instances of EGORefereshTableHeaderView

Comment: @barbgal I'm having the same problem, I got NSZombie in the second use, and if I remove the `[view release]` the app runs well, but I dont get the reload animation in the second view, I only see empty space before the header.. did you solved this?